# Django join on multiple foreign fields (left join)

Tags: django, django-models

I'm using django 1.10 and have the following two models

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    text = models.TextField()

class UserPost(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

How do I get a list of all the posts including the 'approved' property for the logged in user if exists? So instead of multiple queries, it would be one left join query, pseudo-code:

```
select * from posts as p 
left join user_posts as up
on up.post_id = p.post_id
and up.user_id = 2
```

Output

```
post_id | title | text  | user_id | approved
1       | 'abc' | 'abc' | 2       | true
2       | 'xyz' | 'xyz' | null    | null
3       | 'foo' | 'bar' | 2       | true
```

I created the models this way because the 'approved' property belongs to the user. Every user can approve/reject a post. The same post could be approved and rejected by other users. Should the models be setup differently?

Thanks

**Update:**
I'm trying to create a webpage to display all available posts and highlight the ones that the current user approved. I could just list all posts and then for each post check if the 'UserPost' table has a value, if yes get the approved property else ignore. But that means if I have 100 posts I'm making 100 + 1 calls to the db. Is it possible to do 1 call using ORM? If this is not possible, should the models be setup differently?

Comment: You want django orm query?

Comment: Yes. I'd like to avoid raw sql queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then I think you need something like this:

```
Post.objects.all().annotate(
    approved=models.Case(
        models.When(userpost_set__user_id=2, 
                    then=models.F('userpost__approved')),
        default=models.Value(False),
        output_field=models.BooleanField()
    )
)
```

Comment: This only returns posts for user 2, not all posts including user 2.

Comment: What's the difference? You only have one foreign key to User and it's non-nullable.

Comment: I'm trying to create a webpage to display all available posts and highlight the ones that the current user approved. I could just list all posts and then for each post check if the 'UserPost' table has a value, if yes get the approved property else ignore. But that means if I have 100 posts I'm making 100 + 1 calls to the db. Instead of one call. If this is not possible, should the models be setup differently?